# inet_ntop() not printing url

Tags: c, sockets, server, network-programming

I believe the inet_ntop() is supposed to convert a struct sockaddr address to a string, currently I have :

```
 sin_size = sizeof their_addr;

 new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);

 inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&their_addr)->sin6_addr), s, sizeof s);

 printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);
```

If I make a connection from http://localhost:3490/thispage.html, I expect the code to print out
http://localhost:3490/thispage.html but all it prints out is "server: got connection from ::1".

I don't understand why this is happening - basically what I'm trying to do is get the html page name from the url and I wanted to extract it from the returned string, but the string is not returning what I was expected.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. This only deals with IP and IPv6 addresses, it has nothing to do with URLs.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is the HTTP `Referer:` header.

Comment: Do you know how I could get that in a c program?

Comment: If the C program is acting as a webserver, it needs to read the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inet_ntop` function takes a structure containing an IP address and converts it to a string format.  It doesn't know anything about URLs.

When `accept` returns, all that's happened at this point is that a TCP connection was made, and `their_addr` contains the IP address of the endpoint which connected, in this case ::1, which is what is printed.

You need to further read from the socket, which presumably contains HTTP, to learn what URL was called.